# Lock iPhone with home button

Tags: iphone, ios

I have an iPhone SE under iOS 12.3.1 and I would like to be able to lock my iPhone using the home button by holding the button for instance. My lock button isn’t responding for a while and Assistive Touch is quiet annoying for a small screen like mine. 
Any suggestions? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to use Home button to lock your iPhone. If your iPhone's lock button is broken, using assistive touch is your only resort.

[image]

You can optionally set up your iPhone to auto-lock. The minimum duration you can set for auto-lock is 30 seconds.

[image]